# How to send email with JavaScript/react and firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, sendmail

Currently, I'm using firebase to save data and react to build my website.
So, problem is I have to send email to user that log in my website.
I have no ideal to implement it.
How to get data on firebase and how to send email with information I have from firebase?

Comment: You will need a server to send emails. Since you are already using Firebase, you can check Firebase Cloud functions. Here is how to do it from the official repo: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js

Comment: That's OK, i will read it carefully, Thanks you @tugce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest and most reliable way to send emails would be to use an Email Service/API like SendGrid. They provide documentation and libraries to easily integrate:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html

More providers:
https://www.ventureharbour.com/transactional-email-service-best-mandrill-vs-sendgrid-vs-mailjet/

Comment: this's  exactly  what i need,  thanks you @Bobz79 , 
take care of yourself and have fun,

Comment: You're welcome! You may accept the answer if that is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are emailing in response to a database event, ie registration then using cloud functions abs a Gmail account would be more approachable and affordable. Plus there are tutorials in the docs for doing this!

Comment: i'll try this, thanks you